# Choosing more complicated path to element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code which gets one of `input`'s to show/hide some information when it's chosen.

```
    $("input[name$='payment']").click(function() {
```

Everything works as it should, however, my website let's user to click whole `table` element to tick the input. 
How can I tell jQuery to choose whole element, not only the small input ticker if my code looks like this:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
              <tbody><tr class="moduleRowSelected" onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)"">
                <td width="10"><img src="cat/pixel_trans.gif" width="10"></td>
                <td class="main"><b>Name of payment</b></td>
           <td class="main"><input name="payment" value="importantpaymentwithexternalinformation" type="radio">                    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target the tables containing those elements using `.closest("table")`:

```
$("input[name$='payment']").closest("table").click(function() {
// ------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Within the `click` handler, `this` will refer to the table. Since a user clicking the table may not click the radio button, you'll want to include code to do that for them:

```
$(this).find("input[name$='payment']").prop("checked", true);
```

Example:

```js
$("input[name$='payment']").closest("table").click(function() {
  $(this).find("input[name$='payment']").prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="moduleRowSelected">
      <td width="10"><img src="cat/pixel_trans.gif" width="10"></td>
      <td class="main"><b>Name of payment</b></td>
      <td class="main"><input name="payment" value="type1" type="radio"> Type 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="moduleRowSelected">
      <td width="10"><img src="cat/pixel_trans.gif" width="10"></td>
      <td class="main"><b>Name of payment</b></td>
      <td class="main"><input name="payment" value="type2" type="radio"> Type 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="moduleRowSelected">
      <td width="10"><img src="cat/pixel_trans.gif" width="10"></td>
      <td class="main"><b>Name of payment</b></td>
      <td class="main"><input name="payment" value="type3" type="radio"> Type 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly it doesn't work and I have no idea why, because adding .closest("table") should work, but it stops to work totally. Also ticking exactly on input radio is no longer working if closest-table is added :(

Comment: @jampjamp: No, I'm afraid not. There's no way for me to know, since I can't see the code. The above demonstrably works, so...